# Error trying to connect to MySQL Database in AWS RDS through tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, amazon-rds

I want to create a web application using Html, Jsp and java. I am working in eclipse kepler IDE and have Tomcat 7.0.34 installed on my PC. My project is of type "Dynamic Web Project" and in my Build path I have already set the mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar

My database is in MySQL on AWS RDS. I was able to access the database easily when I was running my application as a simple "Java application"

But when I tried running it on Tomcat server I am getting the following error :

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WelcomeCustomer.jsp at line 53

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page     /WelcomeCustomer.jsp at line 53

50:      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
51:         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
52:         String Cust_address, Cust_email, Cust_contact;
53:         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
54:         
55:         //View all shops
56:         Statement stmt5 = con.createStatement();


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:5    68)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for     jdbc:mysql://myAWS_URL     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
```

Please help 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Include mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar in your .classpath file.

Comment: yes it is already configured, yet i am getting the error